# Auto or faster deployment to Digitalocean droplets

Tags: node.js, deployment, digital-ocean

The steps I take to deploy my NodeJS app to my DigitalOcean server

1. git push to my github repo
2. git pull to my droplet space
3. npm start to start my server

surely it will be better to make these steps a bit automated

but there's more bad issue

the server takes about 30 minutes to reflect my updates

so I have to wait about 30 minutes to see my updates (so bad)

even when I turn off my droplet , my browser still render the website normally

it looks take the same 30 minutes to see that the server is closed !!